# I have updated to Python 2.7.14 which should support TLSv1.2 but still doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, tls1.2

I have an https url that has TLSv1.2 certificates,  I have updated to Python 2.7.14 from 2.7.9 which should support TLSv1.2 but still doesn't work:

```
>>> import urllib>>> urllib.urlopen(url)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 443, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1263, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 363, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 611, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 840, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:661)
```

Comment: Have you checked that this is in fact Python 2.7.14? `$ python2.7 --version`

Comment: @ErikCederstrand I have a proxy in between

Comment: The proxy didn't support secure connections I added the proxy only for http connections

Answer (score 1):

It was a compounded problem

1. The url was requiring TLSv1.2 (2.7.9 didn't support it) I had a
2. proxy that didn't support https

And although I fixed 1. the other issue (2.) was giving the same error

**Solution:**

1. was fixed by upgrading to Python 2.7.14
2. The proxy I had didn't support https so I added and exeption and now it works

(leave "for all protocols" checkbox empty and for the **Secure** section leave the address and port empty)

[image]